# How can I pass a variable through a segue?

Tags: variables, ios5, xcode4.2, uistoryboardsegue

Is it possible to pass the value of a double (for example) through a Segue?  Given the sample code, I'm trying to pass the value of a UIStepper (a double) through the Segue to another view.  I know I have to declare the double on the other controller, but I'm not sure if this is even possible.  What do I have to declare in the other View Controller to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

-PaulS.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"home2Segue"]) 
    {
        double classLength = stepperClassTime.value;

        home_1_ViewController *vc = (home_1_ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        vc.classLength = classLength;  

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine if you add `classLength` as a property in your `home_v1_ViewController` class:

Header file (.h):

```
@property (nonatomic) double classLength;
```

Implementation file (.m):

```
@synthesize classLength;
```

Comment: Turns out I was doing the same thing, I just had a typo.  I had classLenght boy a typo can really ruin your day...

Comment: At least you got to confirm that you were doing the right thing. :-)